# How to set updated value to Multiple spinner using same array?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am **creating spinner dynamically** as user enter value in **textField**.

- If user enter three  then three spinner get created and all these spinner use same array.
- If user select one value of spinner then these value will be deducted from  other spinner list
- I use **onItemStateChangeListener** but problem is that when i remove value from array then other spinner has also use same array so changes are reflected in all spinner so i am not geting desire output .
- I want the element to display then remove but not show in next spinner list but not getting any solution.

**how can i overcome these problem,please help me**

Comment: In short: you can't ... not so short ... use [Filterable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface (but in result you would be another array with same objects)

Answer (score 0):

You must have to call `spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` or `spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);` after removing element from array, for next spinners.